# Best way to install some Linux distros in the cloud and record screen

Tags: linux, ide, cloud-computing

I am looking to record some training on a few Linux distributions.

Will something like Microsoft Azure be able to do this or online IDE or perhaps DigitalOcean? I will download, upload the ISO and then boot the distro.

ideally it would be great to run VMWare Workstation or something online.

I need to run the GUI and see the screen like a user of the distro would see it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You typically select an (installed) image when creating a VM.
Better look at http://packer.io